# Flutter: Future build

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I just need some guidance on how to use future build.
I have an app that should fetch some data on my live server. The fetching of data was successfully fetch and i want to display those on listingview widget. But sadly, it just return null with no error (i think).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU30v.png) -> please check image.

Here's my Code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:phc_gps_sms/constant.dart';
import 'package:phc_gps_sms/network_utils/api.dart';

class TipsCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
const TipsCarousel({
Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

_getGuidlines() async {
  var res;
  res = await Network().getData('/guidlines');
  var body = json.decode(res.body)['guidlines'];
  print(body);
  return body;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Tips',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => print('See All'),
            child: Text(
              'See All',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  letterSpacing: 1.0),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 300.0,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getGuidlines(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('snapshot.error'),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text(snapshot.data['index']['title']);
              },
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    )
  ],
);
  }
}
```

I am new to flutter so please go easy on me.

Comment: share JSON response

Comment: "I am new to flutter" > FWIW I started off using FutureBuilders in my app where I had network fetches but ended up changing to stateful widgets or stateless widgets watching a Provider and then conditional build()s. This approach I found both more intuitive and more powerful. I could show a CircularProgressIndicator() when my data was empty, then handle different conditions like success, network error, success but missing data, etc. in the same widget. Updates get triggered automatically with setState or watch() just like with a future builder, the difference is you have some if()s in build()

Comment: @Benyamin 

[{id: 1, title: asdasd, subtitle: asdasd, content: <p>asdasdasd<br></p>, banner_name: d6a4b60af260cdaf8a50ca461a9abb17.jpg,  published: true, created_at: 2021-09-19T15:24:39.000000Z, updated_at: 2021-09-19T16:11:51.000000Z, type_id: 1, topics: [{id: 1, name: asdasd, created_at: 2021-09-19T15:24:21.000000Z, updated_at: 2021-09-19T15:24:21.000000Z}, {id: 1, name: asdasd, created_at: 2021-09-19T15:24:21.000000Z, updated_at: 2021-09-19T15:24:21.000000Z}], type: {id: 1, name: asdasd, created_at: 2021-09-19T15:24:23.000000Z, updated_at: 2021-09-19T15:24:23.000000Z}}]

Comment: i think there's no problem on fetching data, the problem might lie on snapshot. @Benyamin

Comment: Actually I already display the fetched data on different layout/design . I just wanted to change the layout to be more user friendly and redo the process but suddenly the future build return empty although I can print the data on debug output.

Comment: check this: (snapshot.data['index'])['title']

Comment: thanks @Benyamin yeah, the problem was there ['index'] ... it should be without quotes. thank you for pointing out. I already got it last day though. :)